# Align elements on the same line html

Tags: html, css, label, vertical-alignment

I want to align 'Header' label with the others span labels on the same work. I tried display: inline-block but it didn't work. How can i make it? Thanks.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Title
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row" >
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label>Header</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <h4><span class="label label-success">Success</span>
                    <span class="label label-info">Info</span>
                    <span class="label label-warning">Warning</span>
                    <span class="label label-danger">Danger</span></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/uct0S6PDIXpNbDCd1p1K?p=preview

Comment: It looks like you are using bootstrap. Ensure that bootstrap is not overriding default span style for display: inline with display: block. If yes then override it back in your custom css

Answer (score 1):

Cut the header label from col-sm-3 div and paste in col-sm-9 with other span label. Then all will align in same order.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Bootstrap, then make sure you are not overriding bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css, for reference working code is given below, in case if you are looking for Mobile Browsers, you need to edit the Standard Bootstrap CSS file bootstrap.css or add the following line to your HTML code inside head(style) tags, Working example given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<style>
.row
{
  display:flex;
}
}
</style>
  </head>

  <body>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Title
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row" style="dispay: block;" >
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label style="padding-top:10px;">Header</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <h4><span class="label label-success">Success</span>
                    <span class="label label-info">Info</span>
                    <span class="label label-warning">Warning</span>
                    <span class="label label-danger">Danger</span></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use below css.

```
.logo-head {
line-height: 39px;
margin: 0 !important;
}
```

add class to label

```
<label class="logo-head">Header</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this piece of CSS with your code it works fine

```
.col-sm-3 { display: table; float:left;    height:40px;}
.col-sm-9 { display: table; float:left; }
.col-sm-3  > label , h4 > span { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
```

### **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/vqktct5s/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/q2hxlWnTP9BLSnhIKd6M?p=preview

Since I couldn't edit your CSS file, I added the following inline CSS:

```
<div class="col-sm-3" style="float:left ; padding-top:12px">
```

Cheers!

Cynthia